# WIndows 7 Classic theme - Menu text color when out of focus

Tags: windows-7, themes

I'm trying to change the Menu text color (the foreground) when a window is out of focus. You can see the actual result is not really readable.

[image]

The first row is the out of focus one.
Do you guys have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The option two, step 7 shows the way to change the menu color when you are using classic theme:
https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/282-window-color-appearance-change.html

Comment: Thanks! But it doesn't specify the out of focus one

Comment: change the menu background color from black to other color, then you can view the text.

Comment: I can't find the "Menu background" voice inside the customization window

Comment: Found. But it is no more consistent with the dark theme